# Dynamic fileds on a drupal node

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a **job** and **application** node types and I'd like to add a field on Job so the recruiter can set dynamic (different between jobs) questions that a user should answer when filling in an application.
How can I display the custom questions on the application form and collect the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [paragraphs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) it allows to create as much fields as you want

Comment: thanks for mentioning the paragraphs module, it'll be useful for doing other tasks. Right now I've resolved to using node_form_alter to display the extra questions on application form and then using rules to save the values in the database.